# Dynamic text field can't take the value jquery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to add/remove items dynamically but I can't take the values of all the elements of the array.

Basically I have this form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <div>
            <label> <span>Team name </span> 
            <input type="text" class="input-field" name="teams[]"> </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span id="num_teams"></span> <label><span>&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Team" class="add_field_button" name="add_field_button">
    <input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" />
    </label> 
</form>
```

It just shows an input box where I'd have to insert the team name and two buttons ; one to go to the next page, and the other one to add a new text field using jquery.
Here it is the jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {



    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
var max_fields = $('#n_teams').val(); //maximum input boxes allowed
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment

        $(wrapper).append('<div><label><span>Team Name </span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="teams[]">  <a href="#" class="remove_field">Delete</a></label></div>'); // add input box
        $("#num_teams").html('Number of Teams: '+x);

    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('label').remove(); x--;
    $("#num_teams").html('Number of Teams: '+x);
})
});
</script>
```

The script above works perfectly: it adds and removes textfields.

The problem that I have now is that I can't take the values of the array 'teams[]' .
in a

```
if(isset($_POST['next']))
```

even if I try to take the values manually like

```
echo $_POST["teams"][0]; and 
echo $_POST["teams"][1]; ect...
```

It just takes the first value (i.e. the one I don't add using jquery). It doesn't 'see' the jquery text fields added.

Of course my final aim is to insert 'teams[]' in a mysql table, but for now I noticed that I can't either take the values.

Where am I wrong ?

**EDIT - SOLVED**
It was a very stupid error I made in the html code. Actually there was a `<div>` before of the `<form>` that caused all the troubles. After a very accurate analysis , trying every single piece of code alone, I finally got that I just had to move the `<form>` above two `<div>` to make the code work.
I do apologize to everyone, silly me!

Comment: Your html code is a mess... the label element is supposed to label the text associated with an input, so your text inputs should look like this: `<label for="team_name">Team name</label> <input id="team_name" type="text" class="input-field" name="teams[]">`. This allows you to click on the text "Team name" and the browser will make the associated input active.

Comment: I changed the html as you suggested, but the problem persists.

Comment: I also changed the append in jquery like this: <label for="team_'+x+'"> to have different labels for the text fields, but it didn't work either

Comment: Sorry -- my suggestion was just for improving the usability of the form/making your html better.

Comment: All right!thank you for the suggestion anyway. I appreciated that

Comment: Have you done `print_r($_POST)` to see what is coming up in your PHP script? Also -- you do have `action=""` defined in your html, right?

Comment: What browser are you running your script on? It isn't working on Chrome using a jsfiddle.

Comment: 1. I'm using Chrome, but I tried also on Firefox with the same results.                                                                 2. Yes I have action="" in the form.                                            3. The output of the print_r($_POST) is the following: Array ( [0] => team1 ) -- It 'sees' only the first text field .. Maybe I'd move the 'next' button in another form ? Could it cause this kind of problems?

Comment: The weird thing is that if I put statically the textfields, they will show up. So it's the jquery script that generates something that can't be taken

Comment: I do apologize if I wasted your time, but it was a very silly error I made in the html. The solution is in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `name="teams[]"` use `name="teams"` and on server side use:

```
$_POST['teams']
```

which should give you the comma separated list.

Comment: It still gives me the first text field

Answer (score 0):

var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap").first();

Comment: where are you getting value of text field? On the same page or other page.

Comment: @devverma I'm getting the value on the same page